# Set Specific uibutton in a uitableviews, properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to set a specific button(s) in a uitableview cell to be inactive and change some of the other properties. Im retrieving a bool from NSUserdefaults which works fine. This is how im trying to do this. - PopularObjectID's is a mutable array with a bunch of strings. This code is in this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And here is the code:

```
NSString *objID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[popularObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@OBJPressed",objID]]) {}
else {
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];




[(UIButton *)[thisCell.contentView viewWithTag:6] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[(UIButton *)[thisCell.contentView viewWithTag:9] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[(UIButton *)[thisCell.contentView viewWithTag:6] setEnabled:NO];
[(UIButton *)[thisCell.contentView viewWithTag:9] setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I think im probably making a really silly mistake here, but im not great with UITableViews.
Hopefully this is understandable, but if not; don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!
(please be nice, im new to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    static NSString* simpleTableIdentifier = @"TSTableViewCell";

    TSTableViewCell* cell = (TSTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Create TSTableViewCell.xib with UITableViewCell (as TSTableViewCell)
        NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: simpleTableIdentifier
                                                     owner: self
                                                   options: nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

    NSString* objID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[popularObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@OBJPressed",objID]])
    {
       [cell.button6 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
       [cell.button6 setEnabled: NO];
       [cell.button9 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
       [cell.button9 setEnabled: NO];
    }
    else
    {
        // Set up button's property by default
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how the .xib would work?

Comment: You need create new xib. Place UITableViewCell. Design it (placing buttons). Create new custom class of TSTableViewCell: UITableViewCell with IBOutlet UIButton s.  Assign in IB for UITableViewCell as custom class TSTableViewCell. Bind IBOutlet s. Hope it is clear. I'm sorry by my english.

Comment: Im using a storyboard in my app. Will this cause an issue with this?

Comment: No. But I recommend create separate xib for cell.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call contentView on cell. Just do this

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[thisCell viewWithTag:6];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Comment: Tried it, still not luck. Thanks though.

Comment: put a break point in your method and make sure that button is not null

Answer (score 0):

If you put that code in
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
You cannot get a cell using
`UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
Since at this moment the cell at that `indexPath` hasn't been created yet. So `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` will just return nil.
What you should do is:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString *objID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[popularObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@OBJPressed",objID]]) {}
else {
    [(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6] setEnabled:NO];
    [(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9] setEnabled:NO];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: I have already got the first 5 lines in my method, but now won't that just change every uibutton in all the uitableviewcells to gray if the bool returns true?